# Sleeping in an inflatable boat

Tags: rivers

I am going to make a trip on a river in an inflatable rowing boat. The trip is going to be two days long: one day down the river and the next day - back.

The question is how I should spend night. I don't have a tent and now am pondering over whether I should buy it or not. Have anybody spent night in the boat on the water? Is it safe? What safety precautions should I take?

The river is relatively calm, it's the Dnieper river in Ukarine, and at the section I'm going to boat at it is about 500 meters (540 yards) wide, current speed is 0,6 - 0,7 m/s (up to 2 miles per hour).

Comment: @nsn Because if I pitched a tent it'd be onshore. I mean mainly safety on the water.

Comment: Sorry, I don get it, migration implies closing the question? It's a good question, it might just belong somewhere else.

Comment: @nsn Outdoors is still in beta, and we can't choose beta sites as a migration target. (A moderator could but no moderators were involved here.)

Comment: @MichaelHampton You can always flag for migration. Just did that now.

Comment: This question appears to of been asked here already